# Showing Items of Custom List

Tags: list-view, custom-list, xslt, row-limit

I created a new custom list then I created new web-part with custom list. I added `xsl` code for the web-part.

I want to five item appears on homepage. If users click on "All Items", they redirect to `allitems.aspx`.  But my `xsl` code is showing all items on homepage. How can I limit to showing number of items? Should I add code in the `xsl` code?

Comment: In the XSL code you can use RowLimit as part of the CAML query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Edit Page -> Edit the webpart -> Edit the current view -> Scroll down to Item Limit. Set it to 5 and hit OK.